# Acumatica - Filter extension field not triggering events

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add a field to the Sales Price UI, something like this:

[Filter field placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5uEI.png)

I've got the filter logic itself working, but editing the field doesn't trigger the filter. i.e. If I change any other field, the filtering works as expected.

Do I need to add a field event and trigger this manually? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have **CommitChanges** in Aspx (Layout Editor) set to ***True*** for your custom field input control?

Comment: Oh My God. I'm ashamed now

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. Glad you can now move forward with your project :-)